# For conditioning and String matching

Tags: java, loops

Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring. So `"xxcaazz"` and `"xxbaaz"` yields 3, since the `"xx"`, `"aa"`, and `"az"` substrings appear in the same place in both strings.

My code: throws a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for some inputs

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length()-1;i++){        
       if(a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(i)) 
           if (a.charAt(i+1)==b.charAt(i+1)){
               count +=1;
           }
    }
    return count;

}
```

Whenever I write code for these types of problems I am always greeted with "Index out of bounds" and I have to change the loop `length(a.length()-1` to `a.length()-2`) or so. Is there any solid way to decide a loop length when the body of the loop goes i+1 or increments heavily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length()-1;i++)
```

Is the correct way to iterate over pairs of characters of the first `String` `a`.

However, you have two `String`s whose lengths may be different, but the condition of the for loop only tests the length of `a`, which may be longer than `b`, so `b.charAt(i)` or `b.charAt(i+1)` may throw an exception.

You should limit your loop by the lengths of both Strings :

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length()-1 && i<b.length()-1;i++)
```

This will avoid the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Or use `int minLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length)`, and use `i < minLength - 1`.

Comment: Shouldn't the for loop be `i<a.length() && i < b.length()` instead of `i<a.length()-1 && i<b.length()-1`

Comment: @iskandarchacra no, since the ody of the loop uses `a.charAt(i + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it the other way round and check for both length of a and b:

```
for(int i=1;i < Math.min(a.length(), b.length);i++){        
   if(a.charAt(i-1)==b.charAt(i-1)) 
       if (a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(i)){
           count +=1;
       }
}
```

This will not enter the loop for string like `"a"` since length of 1 isn't less than 1 and it will limit the loop to the shortest string.